# How can I configure ubuntu to have a static IP address but still use DHCP for other configuration information?

Tags: ubuntu, ip, dhcp

I want to use DHCP to pick up the network configuration information including DNS, but still assign a static IP address.

On OS X, this is "Using DHCP with manual address", but I see no similar configuration option for ubuntu in the GUI, and I can't find any information about how to configure /etc/network/interfaces to do that.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have this exact same question. It looks like perhaps the right answer *for me* is from @Khaled, though... has anyone gotten that to work? The syntax given is a null-op for me.

Comment: Actually, it was working, I just didn't see it (per my `ip addr show` comment below).

Comment: None of the current answers are satisfactory. In my case, I wanted to do this for a VMware guest using NAT networking (vmnet8). I was able to fix this by configuring a static address reservation in VMware's DHCP server config on the host. On OSX this file is in `/Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion/vmnet8/dhcpd.conf` by adding the following:
`host myguestvm {
  hardware ethernet <guest's NIC's MAC address>;
  fixed-address 172.16.xxx.yyy;
}
`
(You need to restart VMware or, prior to VMware v3, restart the DHCP service separately).

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just set up IP address reservations in your DHCP server. This associates IP addresses with specific MAC addresses, so that the same network interface always gets the same IP address. Consult your DHCP server documentation for details.

Comment: That's what I normally do, but apparently that's not possible with the DHCP server we're using (Cisco ASA 5505) - it doesn't support DHCP reservations. Yes, I could switch to another machine for running the DHCP server, but that is more work than what my question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can append the following line to your `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
post-up ip addr add 192.168.0.1/24 dev eth0
```

Of course, you can change the `IP/mask` and interface name to suit your needs.

Comment: That will still use up an ip address reservation slot from the dhcp pool though, right?

Comment: This will just execute the `ip` utility to assign additional IP address whenever the interface becomes up.

Comment: Ideally, I don't want it to grab an ip address from the dhcp pool at all.

Comment: @field: So, just assign a static IP instead.

Comment: That's the entirety of my question - how to assign a static IP address while still using DHCP for the other configuration information. This should be possible somehow.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work for me @Khaled. Has this command changed in recent years? I don't see anything about it in the man pages...

Comment: @DavClark: See `man interfaces`.

Comment: Thanks @Khaled... the other missing piece was that I didn't realize `ip` was just a regular command-line program. But it's working now! The other wrinkle is that this IP doesn't show up in ifconfig, but you can see it with `ip addr show`.